# gimp plugin for drawing by code

Tags: gimp

Is there any way to use console and draw in gimp? Inserting commands for setting paint-stick size, setting beginning and the and of line *in real time* (like in console). Is there something like that?

Or similar program for drawing in 2D?

Comment: It's not exactly what you want, but you could try imagemagick. Then just have the image open in a file explorer.

Answer (score 1):

GIMP possess a batch mode which does what you want to do, I believe.

[Documentation for GIMP Batch Mode](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/)

Comment: Seems that it's not available. I need  something to see thing I'm drawing in real time.